# Pass username from Login component to Homepage component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

If I have a login page component like this...

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: ""
        };
```

and I want to access that username on the homepage to show user-specific information through a fetch how would I do that?

```
class AccountItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username : // How to get the same field as Login username here?
        };
    }
```

Comment: You could save the username in localstorage once loggedIn and then fetch it in AccountItem component

Comment: I will look into that

Comment: Would passing it as props to that component work?

Comment: @Curious13 I'm not quite sure how I would do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to use **React.createContext** if you have **React 16.3**, update your state at the App level, or have a state management system like Redux to keep track of your current username.

> Example with **React.createContext** which I highly recommend using if you don't have a state management

```
// This is where you have your routes etc.
import * as React from 'react';

const UsernameContext = React.createContext('');

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '' };
  }

  onUsernameChange = (username) => {
    this.setState({ 
      username: username
    });
  }

  render() {
    <UsernameContext.Provider value={this.state.username}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" render={()=><LoginPage onUsernameChange={this.onUsernameChange}/>
      </Switch>
    </UsernameContext.Provider>
  }
}


class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ""
    };
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    // This is pseudo code so you want to handle login somewhere
    // when that is done you can call your onUsernameChange
    this.props.onUsernameChange(this.state.username);
  };

  ...
}


class AccountItem extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <UsernameContext.Consumer>
        {(username) => { 
          // you have username in props
        }}
      </UsernameContext.Consumer>
   )
 }
```

Below is a simple example without **Redux** or **React.createContext**

```
// This is where you have your routes etc.
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '' };
  }

  onUsernameChange = (username) => {
    this.setState({ 
      username: username
    });
  }

  render() {
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" render={()=><LoginPage onUsernameChange={this.onUsernameChange}/>
      <Route path="/account" render={() => <AccountItem username={this.state.username} />} />
    </Switch>
  }
}


class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ""
    };
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    // This is pseudo code so you want to handle login somewhere
    // when that is done you can call your onUsernameChange
    this.props.onUsernameChange(this.state.username);
  };

  ...
}


class AccountItem extends Component {

  render() {
    this.props.username // you have username in props
```

Comment: I ended up giving my router a username in its state then passing it to Home and passing it again to AccountItem. This is probably bad design but it works for now

Comment: Another thing you can do is use React.createContext if you're in 16.3 I can post a simple example on how to do that. Which should be the best way to handle this case since App -> Home -> AccountItem

Comment: This is not needed than you @KennethTruong